# Ember renderTemplate relay model

Tags: ember.js

Working hard on my Ember app here, and it's going along fine. However, I've run into an issue of unexpected behaviour and I'm not sure regarding the best approach to this problem.

The problem is that in a specific route, I want to render another route into another outlet. However, the other route that I render into the other outlet doesn't retain it's own model.

If I do this:

```js
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            heading: "Test",
            testContent: "This is test."
        }
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("test", {
            outlet: "left"
        });

        this.render({
            outlet: "right"
        });
    },

    model: function() {
        return {
            heading: "Index",
            indexContent: "This is index."
        }
    }
});
```

... and access the `IndexRoute`, I would expect the `TestRoute`'s model to be rendered into the `TestRoute`'s template, but only the `IndexRoute`'s model is relayed to both templates.

**Fiddle here**:
http://jsfiddle.net/3TtGD/1/

How do I allow Ember to use the default model for a route without having to expressively merge them? It seems tedious.

Also, having the same name of some model properties, like `{{heading}}` is desirable, but not necessary.

What's the best approach for solving this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,
dimhoLt

Comment: I just took a look at this and what Ember recommends you is to set a different controller for a template which needs a different model, see: [link]http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/ Usually I would use a store, from where you can access records and to a controller using `setupController`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `renderTemplate` method you're telling Ember to render a template inside an outlet but it will just default the controller to the one managing the route. Given it's the controller handling the route it makes sense that it manages all the templates within that route.

Of course you can specify a different controller using:

```
this.render("test", {
    outlet: "left",
    controller: 'test'
});
```

it can in turn be a controller you already instantiated (and maybe set its `content`):

```
var testController = this.controllerFor('test');
testController.set(....)
this.render("test", {
    outlet: "left",
    controller: testController
});
```

About using the model: You can call `this.modelFor('test')` inside the route and it will return the model of the `test` route (it even knows if it has already been resolved). I usually do this when I need to access the model of one of the parent routes.

I believe it makes sense to access the model of a parent route, but not so much if you're accessing the model of an unrelated route. Why don't you want to `merge` both models?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, edpaez. My site is very modular, and I currently have a specific route for each module, which in turn can be rendered into (currently) one of two different outlets. This is just a specific combination of the different modules. Whether or not it is correct to use routes here, though, or if the route should basically just be the path and models etc should in turn be generated at that time or something, I don't know, and best-practices advice is always appreciated!