# Multiple Models with Controllers in IndexRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I am trying to show multiple Models in the IndexRoute and have had initial success doing something like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
   return Ember.RSVP.hash({
     documentsA: this.store.find('documentA'),
     documentsB: this.store.find('documentB')
   });
  }
});
```

What I want to do now, is have be able to use controllers associated with these model to do things like show the number of documents, and have actions associated with each model.

Is this possible in Ember?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use the `render` helper. This will initiate a `Documents` controller twice:

```
// index.handlebars

{{render "documents" documentsA}}
{{render "documents" documentsB}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that just creating the controllers for the models worked.  I was thinking about this in the wrong way as the one route to one controller instead of one model to one controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `renderTemplate` hook to specify templates and controllers.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992315/ember-rendertemplate-relay-model/20997348#20997348)