# Different application template for different routes

Tags: ember.js

Given my current router map:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('category')

  this.route('about')
  this.route('contact')
});
```

For the `about` and `contact` route, these need to be rendered via the application outlet as by default. However, for the `category` route, I need it to use it's own template without going through the application outlet.

If this isn't possible and using the application view is necessary, how would I structure my app so that `{{render "header"}}` is nested in the intro div - but only in the category route (while the other routes would use the application template)?

See [my jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huyiyedoka/2/edit) for a better explanation.

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('category')
  
  this.route('about')
  this.route('contact')
});


App.Category = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    
    // render without application outlet?
    
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your CSS here */
html, body {
  margin: 20px;
}


.intro {
  background: #F09819;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.0/ember.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    
    {{render "header"}}

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="header">
    {{link-to 'category' 'category'}}
    {{link-to 'about' 'about'}}
    {{link-to 'contact' 'contact'}}
  </script>
  
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
      <div class="intro">
         {{render "header"}}
         
         <h2>Categories!</h2>
      </div>
  </script>

  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
  </script> 
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </script>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `renderTemplate` method in your Route to tell ember where to render your view. By default ember will render it into the parent template in the "default" outlet.

In your case you'd do something like this:

```
App.CategoryRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
      into: 'posts',                // the template to render into
      outlet: 'posts',              // the name of the outlet in that template, if you omit this property it would be the "default"
    });
    //cal as many renders as you want
  }
});
```

From [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992315/ember-rendertemplate-relay-model/20997348#20997348) might come in handy.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So if I wanted to render the `category` template without using the application template outlet, I would do something like `this.render('category', {into: '??'})`, but what would I put as my `into` property?

Comment: It needs to be a template name. A template of something that has already been rendered. So giving it a second though I think you need to "refactor" your templates so that the application template is always around so you can replace on of its outlets in the `CategoryRoute`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah it should be. I'm thinking of just using a simple/bare application template, and then `layoutName` for about/contact, and a custom template for category - if this makes sense.